# Many parameterised constructors

Tags: java, javascript

Is using 2 parameterised constructors in one class ethical? As each parameterised constructor affects the kind of processing the methods in the class will carry out.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please pick *one* language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only not sure what you mean. You may have multiple parameters in your constructor and you may overload your constructor

```
public Objects(){
 //Do stuff
}
```

That has no parameters. You may overload that constructor with a different signature

```
public Objects(String name){
 this.name = name;
 //Do stuff
}
```

And once again

```
public Objects(String name, int index){
 this.name = name;
 this.index = index;
}
```

Also, please pick a single language tag. Java and JavaScript are NOT the same thing. If you have anymore questions feel free to ask. If this answer helps, mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple constructors with different parameters is perfectly acceptible. However, it should not matter to users of your class which constructor was used. You don't want users of your class to have to keep track of that.

Take, for example, a look at the [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class. It has, among others:

```
String( byte[] bytes )
String( StringBuilder )
```

These are constructors with different parameters, but they both result in an instance of `String`. It doesn't matter to users of the resulting String instance how it was created.   And in the same way, when you create your own classes with different constructors, you'll have to make sure that *those who use instances of your classes, don't have to keep track of which constructor was used to create the instance*. That is the "ethical", or rather, the "good programming practice" part.

So the answer is yes, and you're even encouraged to use multiple constructors if there is a good reason, but make sure that those who use your classes (including future you!) don't have to do any more bookkeeping than is necessary.

**A little extra about having more than one constructor:**

Not related to the question directly, but something you'll run into when you start experimenting with having multiple constructors.
Often, you will find that several of such constructors share basic operations; in that case, you can usually put this code in a separate constructor, that you call using `this`:

```
 class Foo
 {
     private String str;
     private int a;

     Foo( String str, int a )
     {
         this.str = str;
         this.a = a;
     }

     Foo( int a )
     {
         this( null, a );
     }

     Foo( String str )
     {
         this( str, 0 );
     }
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Of course all String constructors return a string. That's true for all signatures of a constructor, always.

Comment: (I mean I know what you wanna say, but you didn't really say it right)

Comment: @IngoBürk I see. I edited my answer a bit.